# Error creating deployment credentials for azure

Tags: azure

I have a website successfully deployed to Azure and it's been working fine.  Recently the website stops responding seemingly out of nowhere with "server encountered an internal error".  It comes back on its own.

To troubleshoot this, I believe I need to FTP the logs from the website to review them.

To get the logs, I believe I need to create Deployment Credentials for the website (I normally deploy from within Visual Studio using a publishing profile.

When I go to create the deployment credentials, I repeatedly receive the error "Failed to Set Credentials with error: 'Cannot modify this user as there is another operation in progress.'"

I am not aware of any other operation in progress.  Is there a way to look at what other operation is in progress?  Does this even sound like a legitimate issue?  Is this maybe a misleading error message where the issue is actually something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We are having the same issue. Bumped.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to access Logs through FTP like this:

1. Set your username and password in `Deployment credentials` section
   [image: FTP username and password]
2. Switch to `Properties` section to see FTP connection details
   [image: FTP connection details]
3. In your preferred FTP client create connection:

   - Server name: `FTP_HOST_NAME:21/LogFiles`
   - User name: `FTP/DEPLOYMENT USER`
   - Password: `Password set in Deployment credentials`
   - Use passive mode
   - No SSL explicit

Answer (score 0):

See this recent link [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0e4c7de1-ae9a-4fee-96b1-6df2f23bbabd/unable-to-create-deployment-credentials?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)
Someone from MSFT says that data center maintenance is happening. Not sure if that's the real reason though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the credentials from the "Get Publish Profile" file?

You can also use the publish profile file to connect with FTP.

Go to the Overview category and click on get publish profile.

Then open this file with a file editor and use the following credentials:

1. userName: the normal username
2. userPWD: the password
3. publishUrl (The one with FTP): the host or server.